# POST an XML file as DOM Document to a php page using Java

Tags: java, php, dom

I want to POST an XML file as DOM Document to a php page (received using Java).

When the Object is received in the php side. I read/traverse the file as a DOM Documents and send another XML DOcument file as response to the post.

Any directions would be very much appreciated.

Here's my sample Java code..

```
private Document sendToServerAndFetchResponse(Document xmlDocument) {

        Document responseXML = null;

        // Create the httpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Url to which the post has to be performed.
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://192.168.0.19:3334/cogglrestservice.svc/InsertTrack");

        // Make sure the server knows what kind of a response we will accept
        httppost.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");

        // Also be sure to tell the server what kind of content we are sending
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        try {
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(xmlDocument.toString(),
                    "UTF-8");
            entity.setContentType("application/xml");
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // execute is a blocking call, it's best to call this code in a
            // thread separate from the ui's
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

            BasicResponseHandler responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

            String strResponse = null;

            if (response != null) {
                try {

                    // Returns the response body as a String if the response was
                    // successful (a 2xx status code).
                    // If no response body exists, this returns null. If the
                    // response was unsuccessful (>= 300 status code), throws an
                    // HttpResponseException.

                    strResponse = responseHandler.handleResponse(response);
                } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }

        return responseXML;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[DOM](http://www.php.net/dom) is available in PHP, too. Your data (the request body) should be available as stdin. Here is a simple demo:

```
// create a dom and load the request body
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml(file_get_contents('php://stdin'));

// create an xpath instance for the document
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// look for nodes and set the attribute
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/foo/bar') as $node) {
  $node->setAttribute('attr', 'success');
}

// send the header and output the document as string
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Demo: https://eval.in/161089

You should recognize the methods of `DOMDocument` from Javas `xmlDocument`.